# Nunit shadow copy dbghelp.dll issue

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, shadow-copy

To ensure that my C# and MC++ application uses a defined version of the dbghelp.dll (from the Debugging Tools) I put it in the appliation directory where all assemblies reside. This works fine on machines which have an older version or even a newer one.

I'm have a NUnit test which calls some functionality from dbghelp.dll. With shadow copy enabled, NUnit uses the dbghelp.dll from the system directory instead of the one which is in the assemblies folder. This fails the test on systems which have an older version of dbghelp.dll in their Windows folder since some functionality might not be available there.

Without shadow copy it works on the same systems, the dbghelp.dll from the assemblies directory is used. Since it's not recommended to turn off shadow copy by the developers of NUnit (and maybe sometimes not configurable anymore), what can I do?